# Iphone text mystery

Tags: privacy, mobile, password-cracking, iphone

A supervisor at work sent a message to a co-worker and me, asking if either one of us would be available to come in early the next day. I waited about 2 minutes after hearing the text indicator go off and when I picked up the phone I saw a message that read sure, what time is the first assignment?

We work in a newsroom so an assignment would be an appropriate question to ask and I assumed it came from the co-worker of mine. I did not look at the phone real close. I responded, of course, and that was that.

I later found out that the message about asking what time the first assignment was, came from me or at least that's how it shows up on their phones, but I did not write that at all.

The only thing I wrote was, of course. How in the world can something like that happen?

Comment: Either A) someone spoofed your SMS, sent a reply as you, then your phone updated its records to include the sent texts or B) you, being human have a fallible memory and just forgot that you sent the text because you were distracted. I'm going to go with B.

Comment: Was this SMS, iMessage or some other sort of text?

Answer (score 1):

You specified in the title that the phone is an Iphone but did not specify if these communications happened over SMS or IMessage. The answers will differ:

**IMessage**: If you have a weak password for your AppleID account there is always the possibility of someone "cracking" your account. Alternatively since you said the message sent made sense and sounds like it came from a knowledgeable person from your field, it may be someone you know. Does anybody you know either know your AppleID password, have access to a device on-which you were or are logged in with your AppleID or have the ability to guess your password based on they know you (i.e. your password is your dog's name appended with your year of birth). In that case, it may just be a friend pulling a "prank" on you. Either way, it is most likely a compromised AppleID that lead to this happening and I would recommend changing/upgrading your password for it ASAP.

**SMS**: Over SMS the commenter Adonalsium is most likely correct. Either:

Option A:

Someone spoofed your phone number and send an SMS as you which is possible but not a simple task by any means and seems odd someone would put in such great effort just to send work texts on your behalf.

Option B:

You did send that message but one way or another forgot you sent it yourself. This type of stuff has happened to me before so you wouldn't be alone on that.

Either way, hope it helps!

Comment: Well, i can promise it was not me that sent the message.  I went to the Apple store to have them take a look through the phone for anything unusual but everything seems normal, strong password, no other devices connected.  I rarely use the phone bc i prefer my Note .  Hmm.  Weird.  I will let you know if it happens again.